# How do I remove the class from an image found on an array?

Tags: php, regex

I use the following code to pull an image out of a post content

```
$content = $post->post_content;
$searchimages = '~<img [^>]* />~';


preg_match_all( $searchimages, $content, $pics );


$iNumberOfPics = count($pics[0]);

if ( $iNumberOfPics > 0 ) {
     // Your post have one or more images.


     echo $pics[0][0];
}
```

But now I ran into a problem, the output of images is including all kind of classes. I would like to know if it's possible for me to remove

```
class="anyrandomclass"
```

from echo `$pics[0][0];` so in the end I get an image without any classes. I found arround a few ways with regex but none of those worked :(

I hope It can be resolve. thanks for the help on this

Comment: Classes can be only in `"` quotes or in `'` quote too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of this regex..

```
echo $finalimg = preg_replace('~class=["|\'](.*?)["|\']~',"", $img);
```

Basically like...

```
if ( $iNumberOfPics > 0 ) {

     echo $finalimg = preg_replace('~class=["|\'](.*?)["|\']~',"", $pics[0][0]);
}
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/142592)</kbd>

[image]

Comment: yes I know! LOL what I mean is when I was trying to use regex before it didn't but your method did work.-

Comment: I'd include single-quotes in regular expression just in case of `class='someclass'` to cover both situations ;)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5, You edited the answer ? Sorry I didn't see .. I too added a support for single quote.

Comment: @Gman, Can you try the code now , it will match for either single quote or double quotes too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `preg_replace` function. Try this:

```
preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', "", $pics[0][0]);
```

This will replace all `class="anydata"` with nothing in `$pics[0][0]` variable.